# Optimal number of fruit boxes and single pieces

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

This is the problem:
You need a certain amount of pieces of fruit (for example: 3 bananas, 2 apples, 10 oranges). A single piece of fruit has some price, depending on the type it is. There's also a set of fruits, containing a certain amount of every fruit for a certain price. I the amount that I get with the boxes isn't enough, I have to buy single pieces, until I have enough. It doesn't matter, if I have too much fruit of some kind.
What's the optimal combination of boxes and single pieces of fruit, so that I get the lowest price?

 
My approach: Determine the maximum number of boxes (so that every fruit would be covered by them) and just loop from zero boxes to the max number. At the end, I take the lowest number as my answer. This approach is too slow, therefore I need something else.

Example: I need 7 apples, 3 oranges and 2 bananas. An apple costs 3€, an orange is 4€ and a banana costs 12€. One box costs 14€ and contains 3 apples, 2 oranges and 1 banana.

Simple solution: Just try every combination from 0 boxes to 3 boxes and see which is cheapest. This is too slow with larger numbers.

Comment: Can you post a more specific example. For instance how could some boxes look like and which prices may they have? Otherwise you get a very general answer  which maybe does not really help-or maybe no answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I hope everything is clear now?

Comment: If you have a large problem maybe linear programming would be a method that would help. Have you thought about that ? Btw, it is possible to buy some single fruits? In this case each fruit can be regarded as a box with one fruit.

Comment: Maybe dynamic programming will be helpful.